# Joda-Time Period issues in some cases

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I have used [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html) **joda-time-2.3.jar**  for day calcution with android app. My code is…

```
Period Nextperiod = new Period(ddate, nextdt,PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
```

In this **ddate** and **nextdt** are **DateTime**
both dates are input type which is format with SimpleDateFormat , For day difference I have used **Nextperiod.getDays()** Now Test case are,

```
Case 1 Right
ddate=2014-06-01T00:00:00.000+05:30
nextdt =2015-04-11T00:00:00.000+05:30
Day: 10
Month: 10
year: 0
```

Case 2 Wrong
ddate= 2014-05-28T00:00:00.000+05:30
nextdt=2015-03-12T00:00:00.000+05:30
Day: 12
Month: 9
year: 0
In case 2 it should be 14 and When I insert 29 may or 30 may the days are 12 same result. I don't know whats wrong with this date. I tested some more date and result are as per my expectation.Let me know my mistake.
**Also tried,**

```
Period Nextperiod = new Period(new LocalDate(Ddate), new LocalDate(Ddate),PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
```

Thanks In advance.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see why the Case 2 example is correct if you try to add 9 months and 12 days to your start date (ddate) step by step.

Adding 9 months to 2014-05-28 results in 2015-02-28. This is the last day of February 2015, so adding 12 days yields 2015-03-12.

This also applies to the test cases with a start date of May 29th or May 30th: the Period between these dates and the end date is 9 months and 12 days.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.Period.between( startLocalDate , stopLocalDate )
```

## java.time

The [accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24077907/642706) by Modus Tollens is correct.

FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Here is the modern version of your code.

Parsing your given strings as `OffsetDateTime` as they include an offset-from-UTC but not a full time zone.

```
OffsetDateTime start = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2014-05-28T00:00:00.000+05:30" ) ;
```

Better to use a time zone than an offset, if known.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime start = LocalDate.parse( "2014-05-28" ).atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

If your really want to work with a date-only rather than a date-time moment, use the `LocalDate` class.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse( "2014-05-28" ) ;
```

You can extract a date-only `LocalDate` from either the `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` by calling `toLocalDate`.

Represent the span of time you want to jump, using the [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class.

```
Period p = Period.ofMonths( 9 ).plus( Period.ofDays( 12 ) ) ;
```

Verify that value by generating a string is standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String pOutput = p.toString() ;
```

> P9M12D

Add the period to the starting date or date-time.

```
LocalDate later = start.plus( p ) ; // Add the `Period` span-of-time to our starting date.
```

To calculate elapsed time, use `Period.between`.

```
Period p = Period.between( startLocalDate , stopLocalDate ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).